# How to get Image Size (Not File Size) in Megabytes (MB) using PHP?

Tags: image, image-size

Is there any way to getting Image size in MB or KB. Actually I can get file size of any image and not found any function to get Image Size. I tried Imagick for this but no success.

getImageSize() function returns only resolution of the images, I think I need to calculate it from there but dont know the way to calculate. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell more precisely what do you mean by _image size in MB_. How is that different from file size in Your opinion?

Comment: Sure, The image size is the size of the image that will be displayed on the screen. This is usaully measured in pixels (rather the dots per inch, often used in publishing). For example 200 pixels x 100 pixels.

The file size is size of the file on the system, usually measured in bytes, Kb or Mb. For example 23Kb.

Comment: So basically You want to get image size in pixels not in megabytes. Right?

Comment: No I need it in Mb, Is there any way to convert pixels to mb?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get it.

Pixels and bytes/bits are completely different units used to measure different things.
There is no simple relation between them. You can't say *X pixels are Y bytes*. The same image in different file formats will weight different as a file regardless of its image size.
Even in one file format two 100x100 px images will vary in file size due to its content's compression effectiveness.

It's like trying to calculate how much one liter (or gallon if you preffer ;) ) of any unknown fluid will weight.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way.
You can use the identify commend from `imagemagick`.
something like

```
exec("identify -format "%[fx:w/72] by %[fx:h/72] inches" {$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']}", $result);
```

or  `Imagick::identifyImage()`  with imagick.

That would give you *image size at a 72DPI*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size by using the `get_headers()` function to get the "Content-Length". The size will be in bytes. To convert bytes to megabytes simply divide it by (1024 * 1024).

**Example:**

```
$url = 'http://www.lyreka.com/images/lyreka-logo.png';
$image = get_headers($url, 1);
$bytes = $image ["Content-Length"];
echo $bytes/(1024 * 1024) . 'MB';
```

Hope that helps someone.